# Violent entry under criminal law act for cohabitants

Tags: england-and-wales

Meet Bob. Bob lives with Alice.

Perhaps they live together as ASTs and flatmates under an HMO, or perhaps he is her lodger. Or, perhaps she is his lodger. If these different scenarios make a difference to the situation legally, please explain how. In any case they both have keys to the front door and this is Bob's lawful home.

Now suppose that one day Bob comes home from work to find the door bolted and latched from inside. He never was given any notice as to this.

But there is a sign on the door saying no entry, and Alice then looks and shouts through the letterbox "please don't come in!"

If Bob enters his lawful home through his window, entering against Alice's explicitly declared wishes, is he in violation of the criminal law act?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139934/discussion-on-question-by-josephcorrectenglishpronouns-violent-entry-under-crimi).

Comment: To clarify the word "violent", does Bob cause or threaten any physical harm to Alice by entering through the window?  If not, "forcible" might be a better term.

Comment: Michael: no. Nate: perhaps, but I've always seen violent entry as a set legal term so I used that and will await further clarification before changing it.

Comment: Has Alice filed a restraining order on Bob, possiblyfor domestic violence?

Comment: Let's say no. -